# (C++) Overloading stuct's operator for struct on right-hand side

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

***The Goal***

I would like an overloaded function that can handle having the struct on the right-hand side of the operator.

*Overload "<<" operator to achieve;*

```
std::cout << vec3 << std::endl;
```

***Where I Am***

*Struct;*

```
struct vec3
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &o)
    {
        return o << x << y << z;
    }
}
```

*Attempts;*

```
std::cout << vec3(0,0,0) << std::end;
```

*Tells me that "No Operator Matches Operands"*

```
vec3(0,0,0) << std::cout << std::endl;
```

*Gives me the desired result, however this is not how I would prefer to layout code like this.*

It may be the case I am misinterpreting the error messages but this is what I am gathering from it.

---

I am struggling to find any particularly concise resources for the syntax required to handle an operation where the struct is on the right-hand side of the operator.
In the form:

```
OTHER_TYPE OPERATOR STRUCT
```

As apposed to:

```
STRUCT OPERATOR OTHER_TYPE
```

Comment: Have a free function: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, vec3 const&)` and then friend it _if necessary_.

Comment: As a member function, the object must be on the left-hand side of the operator, that's how it works. E.g. `vec3(0,0,0) << std::cout` will then be compiled as `vec3(0,0,0).operator<<(std::cout)`. To have the "object" on the right-hand side of the operator the overload must be as a *non* member function. And take the object as the second argument. To be honest, this should have been very clear in any decent [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), class or tutorial.

Comment: Generally speaking, an expression like `a op b` can be either `a.operator op(b)` or `operator op(a, b)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks a lot, it was non-member functions I was missing, It's all working now.